# How can I return to the main menu after entering text for Morse code conversion in Python?

Tags: python

```
kontrol = ""
metin = ""
isInProcess = True
while isInProcess:
    userChoose = input("çıkmak için 'x' e basın, metni morse alfabesine çevirmek için 1' e ,"
                       "morse alfabesini metine çevirmek için 2' ye basın.")
    if userChoose ==  "x":
        isInProcess = False

    elif userChoose == "1":
        print("metni morse alfabesine dönüştürüyorsunuz.")
        metin = input("Lütfen morse alfabesine çevirilmek istediğiniz metni giriniz.").lower()
        morseMetni = ""
        kontrol = ""
        for karakter in metin:
            if karakter in morse_alfabesi:
                morseMetni += morse_alfabesi.get(karakter)
            elif karakter == " ":
                morseMetni += "  "
            else:
                kontrol += " " + karakter
        print('sonuc', morseMetni)
        if kontrol != "":
            print(f"Hatalı Karakter girdiniz!: ({kontrol}) Lütfen sadece alfabe ve rakam karkaterlerini kullanınız.")
```

Let's say I enter some text here after pressing 1 and then I hit enter and it sends me back to where I asked if it was 1', 2' or x'. I want to return to this question after pressing the '*' key

After saying 1, I enter text and hit enter and it sends me back to the main menu

Comment: Do you mean that if you choose "1" in main menu and then only enter "*" as text to convert, the program should instantly go back to main menu?

Comment: No, after selecting 1, I entered text and pressed enter, then it redirected me to the menu again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I updated the code, can you try this?

```
morse_alfabesi = {
    'a': '.-', 'b': '-...', 'c': '-.-.', 'd': '-..', 'e': '.', 'f': '..-.', 'g': '--.',
    'h': '....', 'i': '..', 'j': '.---', 'k': '-.-', 'l': '.-..', 'm': '--', 'n': '-.',
    'o': '---', 'p': '.--.', 'q': '--.-', 'r': '.-.', 's': '...', 't': '-', 'u': '..-',
    'v': '...-', 'w': '.--', 'x': '-..-', 'y': '-.--', 'z': '--..',
    '0': '-----', '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--', '4': '....-', '5': '.....',
    '6': '-....', '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
    '.': '.-.-.-', ',': '--..--', '?': '..--..', "'": '.----.', '!': '-.-.--',
    '/': '-..-.', '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-', '&': '.-...', ':': '---...',
    ';': '-.-.-.', '=': '-...-', '+': '.-.-.', '-': '-....-', '_': '..--.-',
    '"': '.-..-.', '$': '...-..-', '@': '.--.-.', ' ': '/'
}

morse_reverse = {value: key for key, value in morse_alfabesi.items()}

kontrol = ""
metin = ""
isInProcess = True
oncekiAdim = ""

while isInProcess:
    userChoose = input("Çıkmak için 'x' e basın, metni Morse alfabesine çevirmek için 1'e, "
                       "Morse alfabesini metne çevirmek için 2'ye basın.")

    if userChoose == "x":
        isInProcess = False
    elif userChoose == "1":
        print("Metni Morse alfabesine dönüştürüyorsunuz.")
        metin = input("Lütfen Morse alfabesine çevirilmek istediğiniz metni giriniz. '*' tuşuna basarak ana menüye dönebilirsiniz.").lower()
        if metin == "*":
            continue
        morseMetni = ""
        kontrol = ""
        for karakter in metin:
            if karakter in morse_alfabesi:
                morseMetni += morse_alfabesi.get(karakter) + " "
            elif karakter == " ":
                morseMetni += "  "
            else:
                kontrol += " " + karakter
        oncekiAdim = morseMetni
        print('sonuc', morseMetni)
        if kontrol != "":
            print(f"Hatalı karakter girdiniz!: ({kontrol}) Lütfen sadece alfabe ve rakam karakterlerini kullanınız.")

    elif userChoose == "2":
        print("Morse alfabesini metne çeviriyorsunuz.")
        morseMetni = input("Lütfen metne çevirmek istediğiniz Morse kodunu giriniz. '*' tuşuna basarak ana menüye dönebilirsiniz.")
        if morseMetni == "*":
            continue
        metin = ""
        kontrol = ""
        morseKelimeListesi = morseMetni.split(" ")
        for morseKelime in morseKelimeListesi:
            if morseKelime in morse_reverse:
                metin += morse_reverse.get(morseKelime)
            else:
                kontrol += " " + morseKelime
        oncekiAdim = metin
        print('sonuc', metin)
        if kontrol != "":
            print(f"Hatalı Morse kodu!: ({kontrol}) Lütfen sadece geçerli Morse kodu kullanınız.")

    elif userChoose == "*":
        print("Önceki adım:")
        print(oncekiAdim)
```

First, I define an empty variable named "my previousName". This variable will store its value when the user wants to see the previous step.Then, at the end of each step, I assign the result of that step to the variable "previousStep". For example, in the step of converting the text to morse code, I added the line "my previousName = morseText". Also, in the Morse code to text translation step, I added the line "my previousName = text".
Finally, I added an "elif userChoose == "*":" block in case the user presses the "*" key. This block prints the previous step to the screen. I printed the variable "my previousName" from the line "print("Previous step:")".

Comment: yes i have this too but if i enter my answer select 1 then hit enter and press '*' it should redirect me to main menu